# Why is my cycles render background is black?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

It was working perfectly fine with blender 2.8 but I downloaded 3.1 and it became like that, I looked around with the transparency, filter and couldn't find out why (it has lights and everything).

It was just a normal plane background with color. World settings are just normal background with color and everything checked under ray visibility, and honestly not very sure about the differences there as well

[image]

Comment: hello, could ypu please pack your images and share your file? You can only keep one object for example. https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: What are your world settings? did your environment texture go missing perhaps? what did the background look like before? was it an image? a mesh? transparent? or a simple world material?

Comment: @moonboots hi thanks for that! thats new to me, i've packed it and here's the link https://pasteall.org/blend/ac85478762724aad8158ee897c404fcb

thank you so much for the prompt response!

Comment: @Zophiekat i updated the post to show the image previously as i'm not sure how to share it here, but it looked just like that in render mode in 2.8 with some extra lighting, haha sorry i dont really know what i dont know as well, thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given a *Mirror* modifier to your floor, it makes the faces overlap and it creates a *Z fighting*, thus this black color. Just remove this modifier:

[image]

Comment: Oh WOW I APPRECIATE that SO MUCH! Thanks a bunch moon!!